# Reshape wide data to long data with all possible combinations

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to reshape wide data into long format, where I take multiple columns and put them into two columns, including all possible combinations.

Example of wide data:

```
> dfWide <- data.frame("id" = 1:5, "code1" = c("a","b", "c", "d", "a"), "code2" = c("b","c", NA, "c", "b"), "code3" = c("c", NA, NA,"b", NA), "code4" = c(NA, NA, NA, "a", NA))
```

```
> dfWide
  id code1 code2 code3 code4
1  1     a     b     c  <NA>
2  2     b     c  <NA>  <NA>
3  3     c  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4  4     d     c     b     a
5  5     a     b  <NA>  <NA>
```

Desired long format below. I am not worried about the order (i.e., if I combine "a" with"b", I do not need "b" with "a".)

```
> dfLong <- data.frame("id" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5), "one" = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d", "c", "c", "b", "a"), "two" = c("b", "c", "c", "c", NA, "c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b"))
```

```
> dfLong
   id one  two
1   1   a    b
2   1   a    c
3   1   b    c
4   2   b    c
5   3   c <NA>
6   4   d    c
7   4   d    b
8   4   d    a
9   4   c    b
10  4   c    a
11  4   b    a
12  5   a    b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pivot to 'long' format and then use a `group_by` `combn`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dfWide %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(out = if(n() > 1) combn(as.character(unique(value)), 2,
      FUN = function(x) tibble(one = x[1], two = x[2]),
      simplify = FALSE) else list(tibble(one =value, two = NA_character_))) %>% 
  unnest(c(out))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#      id one   two  
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 a     b    
# 2     1 a     c    
# 3     1 b     c    
# 4     2 b     c    
# 5     3 c     <NA> 
# 6     4 d     c    
# 7     4 d     b    
# 8     4 d     a    
# 9     4 c     b    
#10     4 c     a    
#11     4 b     a    
#12     5 a     b
```

---

In the version of `dplyr` is different, we can make the `summarise` to return a single row and then do double `unnest`

```
dfWide %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(out = list(if(n() > 1) combn(as.character(unique(value)), 2,
       FUN = function(x) tibble(one = x[1], two = x[2]),
       simplify = FALSE) else list(tibble(one =value, two = NA_character_)))) %>%
    unnest(c(out)) %>% 
    unnest(c(out))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#     id one   two  
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 a     b    
# 2     1 a     c    
# 3     1 b     c    
# 4     2 b     c    
# 5     3 c     <NA> 
# 6     4 d     c    
# 7     4 d     b    
# 8     4 d     a    
# 9     4 c     b    
#10     4 c     a    
#11     4 b     a    
#12     5 a     b
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error: Column "out" must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3`

Comment: @Cat just checked again the code.  it is not giving an error for me with your example data.  Could be related to package version?

Comment: @Cat is this error based on the same example or a different one

Comment: The error is based on the same example. I reinstalled all packages and updated r.

Comment: @Cat I am using R 3.6.2 and the devel version of `dplyr`, but it should work for the CRAN version because we are wrapping with `list`

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on, then. I will have to come back to this another time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is not having the devel version of 'dplyr'. I've spent the better part of the day trying to install, but cannot get it to load. Is there any workaround in the answer you provided to be able to work with the CRAN version?

Comment: @Cat lets' try to debug the issue. Are you getting output with `dfWide %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = TRUE)`

Comment: Yes, and `group_by(id)`. I get `# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   id [5]`

Comment: @Cat ok, so i think the issue is with `summarise` step`.  Is it possible that you also loaded `plyr`, then use  `dplyr::summarise(..`

Comment: I double checked plyr wasn't loaded and added `dplyr::summarise` and Im still getting the same error

Comment: @Cat Do you get error for this `dfWide %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% summarise(out = list(tibble(one = 1, two = 2)))`

Comment: @Cat If that doesn't work, then it is a version issue

Comment: @Cat I think this should work `dfWide %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(out = list(if(n() > 1) combn(as.character(unique(value)), 2,
       FUN = function(x) tibble(one = x[1], two = x[2]),
      simplify = FALSE) else list(tibble(one =value, two = NA_character_)))) %>% unnest(c(out)) %>% unnest(c(out))`